# Can grep show matching part of line with "context"?

Tags: git, sed, grep

Say I have this text-file (lorem.txt):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua.
```

If I use `grep` I can now easily find the row containing `eiusmod` by:

```
$ grep eiusmod lorem.txt
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
```

By using some sort of context-switch like `-C` I can even get the lines surrounding the match:

```
$ grep -C1 eiusmod lorem.txt
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
```

This is good. But what if **I just want to see some of the characters closest to the match on the same line?** Not the full line. So a behaviour like this:

```
$ grep --char-context=3 eiusmod lorem.txt
do eiusmod te
$ grep -n --char-context=5 dol lorem.txt
1:psum dolor si
3:e et dolore m
```

I could of course do this with some clever sed, awk or other tool:

```
$ sed -n '/dol/{=;s/.*\(...dol...\).*/\1/p}' lorem.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/:o/'
1:um dolor 
3:et dolore
```

But that is not what I want. It's too complicated and obscure to be usable on a day-to-day basis. So is there a simpler way or tool to achieve this?

This is mainly a problem when doing recursive grep over files with long lines like minified css or other files with long texts without newlines. I first started thinking about this when using `git grep` so a solution usable both for plain `grep` and `git grep` is preferred.

**Note** also that a `grep-pipe-sed` construct is undesirable since that will remove any highlight/colorisation of the match.

Comment: I suspect you ask about range quantifiers, e.g. `grep -o '.\{0,3\}eiusmod.\{0,3\}' lorem.txt`, see [this `grep` demo](https://ideone.com/ZIs8W1)

Comment: I did not find the `-o` option earlier. Perfect. Its close enough for me. But its not working on `git grep` I think.

Comment: @UlfR the suggestion by Wiktor prints the match and three characters of context on either side. How is this not what you wanted?  Oh, I see, you want the context to not be coloured!

Comment: How about `grep -o '.\{0,3\}eiusmod.\{0,3\}' | grep --color eiusmod`?

Comment: Did you try `git grep -E --all-match '.{0,3}eiusmod.{0,3}'  lorem.txt` or `git grep -E --all-match '.{0,3}eiusmod.{0,3}' lorem.txt | grep --color eiusmod`?

Comment: Are you still looking for solutions beyond what suggested by Wiktor ?

Comment: @dash-o it would be nice to wrap it up in an alias both for `grep` and `git grep`. But I haven't been able to get that working, so please give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

Solution based on Wiktor Stribiżew comment above.

Possible to create 'grep-cxt', which will take 2 mandatory parameters (# of characters around pattern, pattern) and optional list of files (default: stdin).

```
#! /bin/bash
count=$1
pattern=$2
shift
shift
grep -E --all-match ".{0,$count}$pattern.{0,$count}" "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -noE '.{,4}dolor.{,4}' lorem.txt
```

It returns:

```
1:sum dolor sit
3: et dolore ma
```